# Where to start... location awareness?

Tags: geolocation

I'm working on a restaurant reviews app and I'm not sure what to use for location awareness..  I am developing it in ruby on rails.  What I wan't it to do is have the ability to search for places nearby a user's entered location or guess the user's location based off their ip address as well as off of geo coordinates or w/e too.  Honestly I don't know where to start anyone have any good api / gem / article suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [geokit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/) gem for the backend, and the [WC3 Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) for getting location info from users.

Comment: I was doing some poking around and some say this doesn't support rails 3?  Do you know if this is true?.. I couldn't find anything on their github or web page...

Comment: Sorry -- just saw this comment. I know it's been a while, but in case you didn't figure it out, there is a geokit-rails3 gem which works great.